# Why is it showing different count in Android app?

Tags: support, bug

I see a difference in count when using SE android app and browser. I don't think it's because of cache. I noticed this change few days back and still there is a difference in count.

Here is the browser screenshot

[image]

Here is the App screenshot
[image]

Example have a loot at `7` tag. It's showing score as `74` at android app and `69` in browser. Also look at the `services`, `rest` tags.

I think it's not cache. I've seen it 24hrs back and checked again.

What could be the reason? Any idea?

Comment: Errrr.... caching? ;)

Comment: @Mołot Caching?!! cache exists even after 24hrs time? Now I see count became 75 for tag `7` ;)